# Can I add Pods in Custom framework?

Tags: ios, swift3

I have the custom created framework.
I want to use CryptoSwift Pods in this framework.
First, I create a custom framework and I can use this framework(From Frameworks folder Example.framework) from another project.
Second, I installed CryptySwift Pods to these frameworks
How can I install Pods programmatically in custom frameworks and used it in other projects?

Answer (score 0):

Not understanding you exact question but if you want to create your own framework and you are using any third party then you can create your framework with your own files and then when you will use your framework in another project then ask developer to install those third party pods or frameworks into their project. It will help to avoid conflict if developer also using same framework or pod in their project.

Comment: Yes How can I use my own framework in release (archive file)..Now I can able to use my custom framework in debug, but I cannot use in a release.It got not known mycustomframework name in archive

Comment: When you are creating framework, go to edit scheme and change status from debug to release. While creating framework don't select simulator or any device. You can easily get tutorials to create custom framework. If you will still get stuck then reply, I will check good tutorial and share with you.

Comment: Yes can you plz reference some link,coz I am problem archive with custom framework

Comment: I haven't tried but raywenderlich is best. https://www.raywenderlich.com/5109-creating-a-framework-for-ios

Comment: Use this, it will help you to create framework for both debug and release mode
https://medium.com/curofy-engineering/creating-your-custom-objective-c-framework-for-ios-apps-5d5ccf95c6c7

Comment: @ChaaruuJadhav how will my framework build if i dont add the 3rd party framework in it ?. I can ask the developer who uses my framework to add the pods but first i need my framework which uses the pods to build and for that i will have to add the 3rd party framework in my custom framework. Can you please help me if i wrongly understood